# Oracle - strategy for large number of inserts but only using last insert in an OLTP environment

Tags: oracle, indexing, insert, history

I am inserting 10000 rows into an Oracle OLTP table every 30 seconds. This about 240Mb of data every half an hour. All 10000 rows have the same timestamp which I floor to a 30 second boundary. I also have 3 indexes one of which is a spatial point geometry index (latitude and longitude). The timestamp is also indexed.

During a test the 2 CPUs showed 50% utilization and Input/Output showed 80% with inserts doubling in duration after a half an hour.

I also select from the table to get the last inserted timestamp 10000 rows by using a sub-query to find the maximum timestamp, due to this being two different processes (Python for inserts and google maps for select). I tried to employ a strategy whereby I tried to use the current time to retrieve the last 10000 rows but I could not get it to work even when go for the before last 10000 rows. It often returned no rows.

My question is how can I retrieve the last inserted 10000 rows efficiently and what type of index and/or table would be most appropriate where all 10000 rows have the same timestamp value. Keeping the insert time low and it not doubling in duration would however be of more importance, so not sure whether a history table is needed in addition while only keeping the last row in the current table; but surely that will double the amount of IO which seems to be the biggest issue currently. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database can "walk" down the "right hand side" of an index to very quickly get the maximum value.  Here's an example

```
SQL> create table t ( ts date not null, x int, y int, z int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> begin
  2   for i in 1 .. 100
  3   loop
  4      insert into t
  5      select sysdate, rownum, rownum, rownum
  6      from dual
  7      connect by level <= 10000;
  8      commit;
  9   end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> create index ix on t (ts );

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> select max(ts) from t;

MAX(TS)
---------
12-JUN-20

1 row selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1223533863

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |      |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE            |      |     1 |     9 |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| IX   |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          6  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         92  consistent gets
          8  physical reads
          0  redo size
        554  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        383  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

So 92 consistent gets is pretty snappy...However, you can probably go better by jumping the very last leaf block with a descending index read, eg

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (
  3  select ts from t order by ts desc
  4  )
  5  where rownum = 1;

TS
---------
12-JUN-20

1 row selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3852867534

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                       |      |  1184K|    10M|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| IX   |  1184K|    10M|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          9  recursive calls
          5  db block gets
          9  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
       1024  redo size
        549  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        430  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

So your current index is fine.  Simply get the highest timestamp as per above and you're good to go